# SQL Server Conditional Left Outer Join

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, left-join

I'm not even sure if my question title is the right terminology for my problem, but here we go.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT          C.ID, C.Name, RCR.Mandate_Level, COUNT(CRR.ID) as Num_Requirements
FROM            tbl_role_certification_rel as RCR
INNER JOIN      tbl_certification as C
ON              C.ID = RCR.Certification_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_certification_requirement_rel as CRR
ON              CRR.Certification_ID = C.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_requirement as RQ
ON              RQ.ID = CRR.Requirement_ID  AND RQ.Status = 'Active'
WHERE           RCR.Role_ID = 15
AND             C.Status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY        C.ID, C.Name, RCR.Mandate_Level, RCR.Sort_Order
ORDER BY        RCR.Sort_Order;
```

Which should return:

```
5   Certification 2 Optional    2
8   Certification 5 Optional    2
4   Certification 1 Recommended 0
```

but instead returns

```
5   Certification 2 Optional    2
8   Certification 5 Optional    3
4   Certification 1 Recommended 0
```

Certification 5 does have 3 associated requirements, but one is not active. I had thought that adding `AND RQ.Status = 'Active'` to the second left outer join would provide the correct results, but instead it appears to be ignored when the query is executed.

I have used AND conditions on joins before that worked, so I'm not sure what the issue is this time. I know I can solve this by doing a sub-query, but it would be preferable not to.

I can provide table definitions and sample data if necessary.

Edit: Here's the tables w/ data - http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/6598/tablesc.png
Columns with numbers are defined as integers, columns w/ text are varchars.

Comment: _I can provide table definitions and sample data if necessary._  yes please, they are always helpful.

Comment: @nonnb - Either of your suggestions will result in Certification 1 being left out of the results completely, which would be incorrect. Thanks for the link though, I'll take a look.

Comment: Try `HAVING RQ.Status = 'Active'` after the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: @bfavaretto - Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it excluded Certification 1 again.

Comment: If you run the query without the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses, do you get the output you expect?

Comment: try this, Change COUNT(CRR.ID) as Num_Requirements to COUNT(RQ.ID) as Num_Requirements

Comment: @EricZ - Oh, that totally did it! I was working from a previously-existing query and just trying to tack stuff on. My fault for not starting from scratch.